# Select box use with .mouseup return false issue

Tags: javascript, select, jquery, dynamic-data

I am following this tutorial:

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/live-table-edit-with-jquery-and-ajax.html

My addition is most content is ajax/json/dynamic. I have added a select box which is also populated dynamically. When I try to select something in the select dropdown it automatically closes. I assume due to this:

```
$(".editbox").mouseup(function(){
    return false
});
```

I have tried to use some variation on this:

```
$('input[type=select]').click(function(event){event.stopPropagation()});
```

But I am further down the rabbit hole than my current understanding allows. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It could be an issue with event delegation. There are a lot of good articles if you search Google for it and it's a pretty simple concept.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'm reading up on event delegation now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by wrapping the code in your tr's click event with an if statement that checks which element was actually clicked. This will cause your code to only hide/show the inputs when the user clicks directly on a `<td>` or `<span>` with the appropriate class. That will allow you to get rid of the '.editbox' mouseup event handler.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/craigm/gKaUy/) (The first row in the fiddle displays a select box instead of just two inputs so you can see that this code works. The ajax call is also commented in the fiddle.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".edit_tr").click(function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).hasClass('edit_td') || $(e.target).hasClass('text')) {
            var ID = $(this).attr('id');
            $("#first_" + ID).hide();
            $("#last_" + ID).hide();
            $("#first_input_" + ID).show();
            $("#last_input_" + ID).show();
        }
    }).change(function() {
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        var first = $("#first_input_" + ID).val();
        var last = $("#last_input_" + ID).val();
        var dataString = 'id=' + ID + '&firstname=' + first + '&lastname=' + last;
        $("#first_" + ID).html('<img src="load.gif" />'); // Loading image
        if (first.length > 0 && last.length > 0) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "table_edit_ajax.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#first_" + ID).html(first);
                    $("#last_" + ID).html(last);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            alert('Enter something.');
        }

    });

    // Outside click action
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).hasClass('editbox')) {
            $(".editbox").hide();
            $(".text").show();
        }
    });

});
```

The relevant code above is:

```
$(".edit_tr").click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('edit_td') || $(e.target).hasClass('text')) {
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#first_" + ID).hide();
        $("#last_" + ID).hide();
        $("#first_input_" + ID).show();
        $("#last_input_" + ID).show();
    }
})
```

Don't forget to remove this code:

```
$(".editbox").mouseup(function() {
    return false
});
```

**Edit:** You'll need to do something similar in the 'document' click handler. Except here, you're ignoring the clicks if the target has the 'editbox' class.

```
// Outside click action
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('editbox')) {
        $(".editbox").hide();
        $(".text").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But your dropdown in the jsFiddle is exhibiting the same issue I tried to describe. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: I just fixed the code. See the section of my answer marked edit. This code works for me in Chrome.

Comment: You sir are a scholar and a gentleman. I am off to test this locally. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: No problemo. Please mark this is the answer if it works for you. Cheers! (This is an example of event delegation, btw.)

Comment: I will. Just wanted to test locally on the off chance I run into a mistake and needed clarification, but wanted to give due diligence before further questioning.